# How can I test TensorFlow Federated using a GPU?

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

I am trying to set up a virtual environment in Anaconda Python, but I keep encountering dependency issues. Please tell me which version of tensorflow_federated is compatible with tensorflow-gpu 2.5.0. The Python version in the virtual environment is 3.8

pip install tensorflow-gpu==2.5.0
pip install tensorflow_federated

I tried changing the versions of tf-gpu and tff through web searches, but I continue to encounter the same problem.

Comment: SO is for programming questions

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to set up a virtual environment in Anaconda Python

Please follow the [Link](https://www.arch.jhu.edu/python-virtual-environments/) to setup a virtual Environment.

> Please tell me which version of tensorflow_federated is compatible with tensorflow-gpu 2.5.0.The Python version in the virtual environment is 3.8

Tensorflow-federated is not compatible with Python versions prior to 3.9.
you need to update the python version in the Virtual environment.